# Vbscript - Access denied when editing AD User

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I'm trying to write a script that connects to Active Directory using Administrator credentials. Then searches the entire domain for a specific username, then updates that user's properties. I've written a script that I think should work, but I'm getting "Access Denied" errors, weirdly enough.

Here's the script, which I've put into sections. Because it's supposed to run through SuperOffice, which has it's own unique environment.

```
Dim strUser, rootDSE, adoConnection, ldapStr, adoRecord, objUser

updateUser()

Public Sub updateUser()
    ADUsername = "john.doe"

    createADConnection()

    If userExistsInAD(ADUsername) = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End if

    objUser.Put "description", "testing"
    objUser.SetInfo
End Sub

Public Sub createADConnection()
    Set rootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    adoConnection.Provider = "ADSDSOObject"
    adoConnection.Properties("User ID") = "mydomain\administrator"
    adoConnection.Properties("Password") = "8g773ggj024g"
    adoConnection.Properties("Encrypt Password") = True
    adoConnection.Properties("ADSI Flag") = ADS_SERVER_BIND Or ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION
    adoConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
End Sub

Public Function userExistsInAD(ByVal strUser)
    ldapStr = "<LDAP://" & rootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext") & ">;(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(samAccountName=" & strUser & "));adspath;subtree"
    Set adoRecord = adoConnection.Execute(ldapStr)
        If Not adoRecord.EOF Then
        userExistsInAD = True
        Exit Function
    End if

    userExistsInAD = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like the account you are running SuperOffice with does not have Domain Admin credentials.  Have you tried running it directly with your account?

Comment: Hi! Yes, if I run the script manually with an admin account, it works. But it needs to run from SuperOffice. That's why I was thinking of adding the username and passord directly in the script. Which is not a good idea I'm aware. I need to somehow run the actual updating from a service or something. I'll have to dig around a bit to find the best solution :)